# Is there any way to declare mutual friend functions for two classes

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, forward-declaration, friend-function

```
class CDB;

class CDM
{
public:
    friend CDB& CDB::Add(const CDM&);
    CDM& Add(const CDB&);
};

class CDB
{
public:
    CDB& Add(const CDM&);
    friend CDM& CDM::Add(const CDB&);
};
```

This code gives me the error : error C2027: use of undefined type 'CDB'. How to resolve this.

Comment: You can't. You have to make one class completely the friend of the other, or make one class nested in the other.

Comment: You need to have instantiated an object of the friend class in order to make the link. For example in CDM, calling CDB::Add operates on what Object? You might be able to get away with it if the functions where static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. There is no way to remove the cyclic dependency.

You should be able to get by with making the class `CDB` a friend of `CDM` instead of wanting to making `CDB::Add()` a friend.

```
class CDB;

class CDM
{
   public:
      friend class CDB;
      CDM& Add(const CDB&);
};

class CDB
{
   public:
      CDB& Add(const CDM&);
      friend CDM& CDM::Add(const CDB&);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a file static function as relay :

```
class CDB;
class CDM;

static CDB& CDBAdd(CDB&, const CDM&);

class CDM
{
public:
    friend CDB& CDBAdd(CDB&, const CDM&);
    CDM& Add(const CDB&);
};

class CDB
{
public:
    CDB& Add(const CDM& other) {
        return CDBAdd(*this, other);
    }
    friend CDM& CDM::Add(const CDB&);
    friend CDB& CDBAdd(CDB&, const CDM&);
private:
    CDB& doAdd(const CDM& other); // will contain the actual implementation
};

CDB& CDBAdd(CDB& obj, const CDM& other) {
    return obj.doAdd(other);
}

// other implementations ...
```