# Forward declaration of two dependend classes with friend function

Tags: c++, class, dependencies, declaration, friend

I have two classes. One depends on the other class and the other one contains a function that is friend to the first class. There's a lot of other stuff in this classes but this is what it boils down to:

```
class LightBase;

class Color
{
    friend void LightBase::UpdateColor();
};

class LightBase
{
    public:
        void UpdateColor();
    protected:
        std::vector<Color> colors_;
};
```

But apparently my forward declaration is not correct. I get this:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class LightBase'
```

I get that `UpdateColor()` is not known by the time the friend declaration is made. But how do I fix it?

Comment: You might do with the other order, `LightBase` just need declaration of `Color`, whereas `Color` need definition of `LightBase` (to know it has member `UpdateColor`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work fine if you will change the arrangement a bit:

```
class Color;

class LightBase {
    public:
        void UpdateColor();
    protected:
        // Color has been declared
        std::vector<Color> colors_; 
};

class Color {
    // LightBase has been defined
    friend void LightBase::UpdateColor();
};
```

As to the use of `LightBase::UpdateColor`, we need to have `LightBase` class defined to use its function member `LightBase`, Since it is not known until then, as you pointed out yourself.

Meanwhile, we can have a `std::vector<Color>` with `Color` not being defined yet, only declared in the scope.

Comment: Thanks, of course! How would I do it if LightBase befriended a function from Color?

Comment: @glades You would have to declare the whole `Color` class as a friend. Check this [answer for elaboration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623805/is-there-any-way-to-declare-mutual-friend-functions-for-two-classes).